# Django BinanceSocketManager works on local machine but doesn't work on Nginx server [binance-apis]

Tags: python, django, websocket, binance

Recently I’m working on a Django project in which I need to get the price of some cryptocurrencies like BTC, ETH, and …

So I used `BinanceSocketManager` in a class that uses `multiprocessing`.

> I used the tutorial from this link:
>
> https://livedataframe.com/live-cryptocurrency-data-python-tutorial/

It works fine on my local machine but when I started to deploy it to Centos 7 server, faced some problems. The problem is that the `BinanceSocketManager` doesn’t call the trade_prices function to pass the received message to it and get the prices.

(I’m using Nginx webserver with Python version 3.6.8 and pip and gunicorn and daphne)
Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing
from binance.client import Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager

global PRICES
PRICES = {}

PUBLIC = 'My-Public-key'
SECRET = 'My-Private-key'


# This method works on development mode but doesn't work on deploy mode!
def trade_prices(msg):
    # I can see these print statements on my local machine terminal but not on the server!
    print("msg : ", msg)
    if msg['s'] == 'BTCUSDT':
        PRICES['BTCUSDT'] = [msg['c'], msg['P']]
    print("PRICES : ", PRICES)


class Process(multiprocessing.Process):
    __instance = None

    @staticmethod
    def getInstance():
        if Process.__instance is None:
            Process()
        return Process.__instance

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        if Process.__instance is not None:
            # raise Exception("This class is a singleton class!")
            pass
        else:
            Process.__instance = self
            self.start()

    def run(self):
        client = Client(api_key=PUBLIC, api_secret=SECRET)
        bsm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
        # The line below works correctly on development mode and calls the trade_prices function
        # and passes the msg to it.
        # But it doesn't work correctly on Centos 7 server when I deploy it.
        conn_key = bsm.start_symbol_ticker_socket('BTCUSDT', trade_prices)
        print("conn_key : ", conn_key)

        bsm.start()


Process().getInstance()
```

what did I do wrong?

Is there any additional Nginx config in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf for Binance websocket that I forgot to use?

Best regards.

***[EDIT] :***

I also asked this question in Binance developer groups in [this link](https://dev.binance.vision/t/django-binancesocketmanager-works-on-local-machine-but-doesnt-work-on-nginx-server/1220/2),
somebody says:

> The problem resides in the way you use multiprocessing. The way you
> call binance wss has no problem. Please dig into how to start
> additional processes using multiprocessing in a python-tech forum

I've added some more explanations about my project:

> I want to show the cryptocurrencies’ price and last24 price change to
> all of my users that visit my website. I made two WebSockets. One
> WebSocket connects users to my Django backend, then when the first
> user connects to the backend, One and just one object of
> multiprocessing class creates forever (singleton design pattern), so
> it doesn’t create any more instance of the class when more users go to
> the website. And this multiprocessing object will be connected to
> Binance WebSocket, get the data from it, and store it in Redis cache.
> Then the first WebSocket gets the data from the cache every 5 seconds
> and sends it through my Django WebSocket to the users.
>
> In other words, the very one WebSocket that connects to Binance, get
> the data and place it in the cache, and the WebSockets that connects
> to users, get the data from the cache and serve it for users.
>
> So There may be millions of connections to the first Websocket that
> connects users to my Django backend, but there should be just one
> connection to Binance WebSocket not millions of connections.
>
> Maybe there were better ways to do this job, but at that time, this
> way of implementing comes to my mind. Any suggestion for better ways
> of implementing?